# Compare elements in lists at a specific position (C#)

Tags: c#, linq

Given **two lists A and B with elements {1,2,3} and {4,5,6} respectively**, how can I **find the maximum of the first elements** when **comparing both lists**.

I could do `Max(A[0],B[0])` = 4 to get my answer.
However I'd like it to be dynamic so that I can extend it for say 100 lists.
I'd like to avoid loops, so how can I do it in one line?

Comment: Please mention the language in which you want the answer.

Comment: @Igor he wants the maximum item from among the first elements in each array.  Two arrays, compare the first elements, return the greater.

Comment: @TAHASULTANTEMURI, C#.  I added it to my title.  Thanks.

Comment: how do you plan to store the 100 lists though, cause you can do it recursively

Comment: you mean 1 with 4 then 2 with 5 and so on then you need greater among them.

Comment: @AimeeBorda why would the lists need to be sorted?  recursion is completely unnecessary here.  this can be done with LINQ easily.

Comment: @TAHASULTANTEMURI I only need to compare the first element in all the lists.

Comment: @Amy that is a type sorry I meant store

Comment: Please explain what kind of outcome you want here, do you want a new list/collection containing `{4,5,6}` since index for index that's the maximum value?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen the outcome seems clear.  He wants the maximum value, a single number, from the first element of each list.  He provides an example in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're starting with an array of lists (or a list of lists, or whatever):

```
List<int>[] lists = ....
```

LINQ to get the first item from each list:

```
var firstItems = lists.Select(lst => lst[0]);
```

LINQ to get the max:

```
var max = firstItems.Max();
```

Combined into one line:

```
var max = lists.Select(lst => lst[0]).Max();
```

Comment: Thanks Amy, just what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

If you use `params` you could pass an arbitrary number of `int` arrays.

```
using System.Linq; // top of code file

public int MaxFirst(params int[][] intArrays)
{
    return intArrays.Where(x => x != null && x.Length > 0).Max(x => x[0]);
}
```

*note: `Where` expression is a guard against empty arrays and null references being passed in*

Test code

```
public void Test()
{
    var largest = MaxFirst(new int[] {1, 2, 3}, new int[] {4, 5, 6});
}
```